# How do I see what optimisation passes are used by LLVM's opt?

Tags: optimization, llvm

I want to understand and modify the passes used in LLVM's `opt` for different hardware architectures.

Answer (score 4):

`opt` can tell you which passes it's running on a given piece of LLVM IR:

```
$ opt -O2 -debug-pass=Arguments example_file.ll -disable-output
Pass Arguments:  -tti -no-aa -tbaa -scoped-noalias -assumption-cache-tracker -targetlibinfo -basicaa -verify -simplifycfg -domtree -sroa -early-cse -lower-expect
Pass Arguments:  -targetlibinfo -tti -no-aa -tbaa -scoped-noalias -assumption-cache-tracker -basicaa -ipsccp -globalopt -deadargelim -domtree -instcombine -simplifycfg -basiccg -prune-eh -inline-cost -inline -functionattrs -domtree -sroa -early-cse -lazy-value-info -jump-threading -correlated-propagation -simplifycfg -domtree -instcombine -tailcallelim -simplifycfg -reassociate -domtree -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -loop-rotate -licm -loop-unswitch -instcombine -scalar-evolution -loop-simplify -lcssa -indvars -loop-idiom -loop-deletion -loop-unroll -mldst-motion -domtree -memdep -gvn -memdep -memcpyopt -sccp -domtree -bdce -instcombine -lazy-value-info -jump-threading -correlated-propagation -domtree -memdep -dse -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -licm -adce -simplifycfg -domtree -instcombine -barrier -float2int -domtree -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -loop-rotate -branch-prob -block-freq -scalar-evolution -loop-accesses -loop-vectorize -instcombine -scalar-evolution -slp-vectorizer -simplifycfg -domtree -instcombine -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa -scalar-evolution -loop-unroll -instcombine -loop-simplify -lcssa -licm -scalar-evolution -alignment-from-assumptions -strip-dead-prototypes -elim-avail-extern -globaldce -constmerge -verify
```

Looking at the source code, this is generally a matter of:

Instantiating a [`PassManagerBuilder`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1PassManagerBuilder.html) and calling [`SetOptLevel`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1PassManagerBuilder.html#a52b96ef67bb93fa3a7b461fe2b73bb4f).
The builder then [adds the passes as part of populateModulePassManager](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/PassManagerBuilder_8cpp_source.html#l00188).

Note that [the default pass orderings have been tuned for C/C++](http://llvm.org/docs/Frontend/PerformanceTips.html#pass-ordering) and may not be optimal for other languages.

Comment: Why they are two Pass Arguments lists?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using clang, use -debug-pass=Arguments options to see what passes are being run at each optimization level

Comment: I am not using clang, but using an IR file generated form another compiler in LLVM IR format, I want to try opt in ( .ll) file with modifying some opt's features to see its impact, mostly want to delete X86 specialized passes